# How to transfer a 2007 excel spreadsheet to excel 2003 without losing functionality

Tags: excel

I have built an excel spreadsheet with filters and formulas.  When I change the format from 2007 to 97-2003 and then send it to a client, the filters are no longer there and they don't work.

How can I save a 2007 excel spreadsheet as a 2003 file type without losing functionality?

Answer (score 0):

A problem can be that some functions(like `COUNTIFS()`) are  strictly a function found in 2007 .They are not a valid function in 2003.

If this is not the case then just save in 03 format and you are good to go.

Comment: The issue is with filters.  Functions work fine.  But if I apply a filter in 2007 and email the file, the filter is lost somewhere in transition.

Comment: refer http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/office-excel-2007-features-that-are-not-supported-in-earlier-versions-of-excel-HA010077823.aspx